# Reading date form excel in form of dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: matlab

i am trying to read date from worksheet by using matlab,the date are presented in form of numbers i.e. (39594) inside excel 
i had tried xlsread but the date also still as numeric
how can i read it in form of regular date. 
is there any ideas?

```
Numbers =xlsread('filename.xlsx');
set(handles.uitable1,'data',Numbers);
```

Comment: that is how excel stores date values - days since its epoch.

Comment: i had try to convert it under excel and i had succeeded, but when i read it under matlab the date also return as numeric